# how to add javascript functionality in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I want to make a django pp which has one of the screens that dynamically adds text fields on the click of button. I am doing this with the javascript code embedded in the html file. This html file is contained within the templates folder of the django app.

This is my code :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Email address " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
</script>
<form method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          Email Address 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
</form>
```

but it displays the button and the field. But when I click button, it does not add the field again. What is the mistake? Does django not allow to use javascript in this way? as javascript is client side and django works at server side?If that is the case then how can I make it work? I am new to django. Please help.

Comment: That looks more or less right.  Does your addInput function not get called when the button is clicked?  Put in a console.log statement in the addInput function to check.

Comment: I have solved the problem.. thank you all for the help

Comment: In which case, it's polite to add a note saying what the problem was, just in case

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question whether it's possible to combine JavaScript and Django. As you said, Django is technology that is used on the server-side, while JavaScript executes in client's browser on the client-side.

However, you can use Django's model to prepare JS code that should be executed on the client side. You can do it in the template's code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var msg = '{{serverMsg}}';
    console.log(msg);
</script>
```

This will be evaluated by Django, that will replace `{{serverMsg}}` by actual value of `serverMsg` model variable.

As far as I know, it won't work if you have your JS code in separate *.js file, because this file won't be parsed by Django.

Comment: no i have no .js file. I have kept both javascript and html code in the same .html file within the template folder of the app. i.e. myapp/templates/myapp/my.html

Comment: You can leave `type="text/javascript"` off of the script tag. That's the default value of type already.

Comment: I look into your JS code and I don't see any place where Django could inject it's model. If you want something to be add dynamically from Django model you need to use `{{ ... }}` operator

Comment: No, it's just a minor nuance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's an issue inside derived views. Try this:

In your base html view add or look for ( this must go in `<head>` tag):

```
{% block scripts %}
{% endblock scripts %}
```

And ( inside `<body>` tag )

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And then in your derived view:

```
  {% extends "your_base_file.html" %}
  {% block scripts %}
      Here goes your js code inside <script>
  {% endblock scripts %}
  {% block content %}
      Here goes your html form
  {% endblock content %}
```

I copied your script into my Django project and it worked just fine.